# factorial designed study within between

Tags: anova, validity

IV1 : alcohol use, IV2: breathing exercise (both of them within subject variable) IV3: gender (between subject variable). My research question is that: ''Does alcohol usage and breathing exercise's effect on reducing excitement differ in women and men ?''. Now, How can I establish a study by keeping internal validity high?

Comment: What is internal validity and why do you want it to be high?

Comment: Is this a secondary data analysis or are you conducting the research to collect the data?  Is this data collected from an experiment or from survey data or some other method of collection?

Comment: I am conducting the research and this is an experiment